# c# radial gradient brush effect in GDI and winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, gdi, brush

I have created a c# windows application and written 75% of the code.  The program allows the user to create a flow chart, and will shade the flow chart shapes according to their status.  I wanted them to become 3d buttons such as [image: Gel Button]  from the website [Webdesign.org](http://www.webdesign.org/photoshop/drawing-techniques/gel-button.13626.html)

Rather than create a PNG for each button, I wanted to create them in C# using brushes or other technique, such as:

```
// Create solid brush.
SolidBrush blueBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.Blue);
// Create points that define polygon.
PointF point1 = new PointF(50.0F, 50.0F);
PointF point2 = new PointF(100.0F, 25.0F);
PointF point3 = new PointF(200.0F, 5.0F);
PointF point4 = new PointF(250.0F, 50.0F);
PointF point5 = new PointF(300.0F, 100.0F);
PointF point6 = new PointF(350.0F, 200.0F);
PointF point7 = new PointF(250.0F, 250.0F);
PointF[] curvePoints = {point1, point2, point3, point4, point5, point6, point7};
// Define fill mode.
FillMode newFillMode = FillMode.Winding;
// Fill polygon to screen.
e.Graphics.FillPolygon(blueBrush, curvePoints, newFillMode);
```

I know WPF has radial gradients, but can I do something simular in CGI?

Comment: I assume you mean "GDI+" and not "CGI"?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Take a look at this [Codeproject article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI-plus/Gradiator.aspx), and then at the Path gradient.

Comment: Thanks, I will have a go at this

Answer (score 26):

Unlike [WPF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.radialgradientbrush.aspx), GDI+/WinForms does not have a `RadialGradientBrush`. However you can achieve the same effect using a [`PathGradientBrush`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.drawing2d.pathgradientbrush.aspx).

Here's an example:

```
Rectangle bounds = ...;
using (var ellipsePath = new GraphicsPath())
{
    ellipsePath.AddEllipse(bounds);
    using (var brush = new PathGradientBrush(ellipsePath))
    {
        brush.CenterPoint = new PointF(bounds.Width/2f, bounds.Height/2f);
        brush.CenterColor = Color.White;
        brush.SurroundColors = new[] { Color.Red };
        brush.FocusScales = new PointF(0, 0);

        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(brush, bounds);
    }
}
```

The `PathGradientBrush` has lots of properties to experiment with to ensure you get the effect you're after.

Comment: There is a huge difference, though. WF's `PathGradientBrush` doesn't paint outside the path. WPF's `RadialGradientBrush` does. So, depending on your requirements, it might not achieve the same effect by far.