# Drawing a Gradient Circle into a PictureBox with VB.NET

Tags: .net, vb.net, graphics, drawing

I have an application that puts images into a `PictureBox` and draws a circle in it.

The application consists of 2 steps:

1. An image is loaded into the `PictureBox`
2. A circle is drawn directly into the `PictureBox` with a given specification of the Radius/Diameter (In Pixels) and the position of the circle's center with the `X, Y` of the picture inside the `PictureBox`. (For example if the given coordinates are `44,44` then the center of the circle will be at `44,44`.

My goal is to use the most efficient method to draw an orange, gradient circle (see image under) into an image already in a `PictureBox`, overlaying it. Preferably, I would like a method that does not save the image to the computer as the image inside the box is uploaded every second.

Also,
I was thinking of using `System.Drawing` to use draw a circle directly into a picture that exists in a `picturebo`x but it doesn't look the best (the circle is grainy and pixelated) and there isn't a working gradient option for me.

An example of the circle I want to draw is displayed in the image below.
I've attached a picture below of what a drawn circle onto the `PictureBox` should look like:
[image: Comparason]

My idea is directly drawing this circle into the `PictureBox` without having to save the picture to the PC, as this image in the `PictureBox` gets updated every second and that won't be efficient.

How can I do this? Is there a function in `System.Drawing` that can do this or a NuGet Package I can use? (Drawing a Orange Circular Gradiant Circle onto an image already present in a `PictureBox`?

Comment: You should look into using a `PathGradientBrush`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example that draws an orange ellipse that goes from transparent at the centre to opaque at the edge inside a `PictureBox`:

```vb
Private Sub PictureBox1_Paint(sender As Object, e As PaintEventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.Paint
    Dim bounds = PictureBox1.Bounds

    Using path As New GraphicsPath
        path.AddEllipse(bounds)

        Using brush As New PathGradientBrush(path)
            brush.CenterPoint = New PointF(bounds.Width / 2.0F, bounds.Height / 2.0F)
            brush.CenterColor = Color.FromArgb(0, Color.Orange)
            brush.SurroundColors = {Color.Orange}
            brush.FocusScales = PointF.Empty

            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(brush, bounds)
        End Using
    End Using
End Sub
```

You can just change way you set the `bounds` variable to make it a circle of the correct size and location and change the colors if you need to.

EDIT: Credit where it's due, I got the basis for that from one of the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3519835/c-sharp-radial-gradient-brush-effect-in-gdi-and-winforms).